# Unity OnCollisionEnter function not registering

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies, collider

I am not able to register my OnCollisionEnter();  I have copied the function from a previous Unity program that works and replicated everything.  The collision between the FPSController should be lowering the TreeHealth.

[image]
[image]

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        print("Colision");
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "TreeTag")
        {
            treeScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<TreeFall>();
            treeScript.treeHealth--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use [OnControllerColliderHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html)? I think you have to use this method instead of [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) if you move the character with the [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) Component.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, is there a way for an OnControllerColliderExit type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to replace the print() function with Debug.Log() and detecting collisions in the tree script and check for collisions from the player.

Comment: hmm thanks for your suggestion, i added the Debug.Log and added collision check for tree. still getting no collision detection.